# Implicit differentiation of $e^x-e^y-2^{xy}-1=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I tried to do this:

$$e^x-e^y\frac{dy}{dx}...$$

I am stumped on '$-2^{xy}$', what it's deriative?

Comment: Write $2^{xy}$ as $e^{xy \log(2)}$, and use the chain and product rule.

Comment: Do you can differentiate $e^{x\dot \log(n)}$?

Answer (score 4):

$e^x-e^y-2^{xy}-1=0$
then write as
$e^x-e^y-e^{xyln(2)}-1=0$
then differentiate

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{xy}=e^{xy\ln 2}$$therefore $$e^x+e^y=e^{xy\ln 2}+1$$and by differentiating we obtain$$e^x+y'e^y=(y\ln 2+xy'\ln2)2^{xy}$$finally rearranging the terms leads to $$\LARGE y'=\dfrac{y\cdot2^{xy}\ln 2-e^x}{e^y-x\cdot2^{xy}\ln 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Here is the formula
$$(a^u)'=u'a^u\ln a$$
then
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}(2^{xy})=y2^{xy}\ln 2$$

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of the chain rule an the product rule.

$u = xy\\
v = 2^u = 2^{xy}\\
\frac {dv}{dx} = (2^u)(\ln 2)\frac {du}{dx}\\
\frac {du}{dx} = y+  x\frac {dy}{dx}\\
\frac {dv}{dx} = (2^{xy})(\ln 2)(y + x\frac {dy}{dx})$